# Color-leveling a tiff image via command-line

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

From a script, I'm trying to apply some **color levels** to a grayscale `.tiff` image, the same as I would do in GIMP.

I've tried using [ImageMagick's `convert` tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php):

```
convert input.tiff -level 102,200,0.85 output.tiff
```

and also

```
convert input.tiff -level 102,0.85,200 output.tiff
```

but all I get is a blank image.

Any ideas?? Are there other ways around?

Answer (score 2):

The .tiff format is not well supported in ImageMagick according to the [support documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#other) for the program so it is unlikely to work as expected, try any other supported image format and you should be able to achieve the results you want.

> The TIFF format is the propriety format for PhotoShop.  However it is
>   so   bloated with features, and has been modified by just about every
>   application   that has cared to use it, that no program, not even
>   photoshop can handle ALL   its variations.  Photoshop however has the
>   best chance at reading it.
>
> I would steer clear of the TIFF image file format unless you are
>   specifically working with photoshop, or the application accepts no
>   other,   better defined, image file format.
>
> I don't use the TIFF image file format, or Photoshop. If you use
>   this format   with IM extensively, perhaps you would like to submit
>   your findings to me,   to include here.  That way you  can help your
>   fellow TIFF users.
>
> Whether a specific software package can read a TIFF, all you can do
>   is try   it and see.  That is the problem with this format.

Comment: Curiously, if I first adjust the levels (via `-levels`) and then _separately_ adjust the gamma (via `-gamma`), it works... I'll try using a different format.